# string replace in Python

Tags: python, string, python-2.7

Want to find an elegant way to replace `xxxxx` part dynamically with an array of values (`xxxxx` is more like a template placeholder for real string values). For example, if the array is `["foo","goo","zoo"]`, I want to generate 3 dynamic strings

```
a="hello values: [xxxxx], have a good day"
```

Dynamic string expected,

```
"hello values: [foo], have a good day"
"hello values: [goo], have a good day"
"hello values: [zoo], have a good day"
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Comment: Why do you have xxxxx?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, just an example of placeholder. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use string replace function.

```
a.replace("xxxxxx", "foo")
```

for a list:

```
src_name = ["foo", "goo", "zoo"]
a = "hello values: [xxxxx], have a good day"
result = (a.replace("xxxxx", d) for d in src_name)
for i in result:
    print (i)
```

output:

```
hello values: [foo], have a good day
hello values: [goo], have a good day
hello values: [zoo], have a good day
```

Comment: Thanks for the help Mrunmoy, vote up and mark your reply as answer.

Answer (score 2):

The perfect use for [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) even though list comprehensions are the newer, more idiomatic way to do it.

```
>>> a = "hello values: [{}]"
>>> names = ["foo", "goo", "zoo"]

>>> map(a.format, names)

['hello values: [foo]', 
 'hello values: [goo]', 
 'hello values: [zoo]']
```

Comment: This is the best Pythonic answer. You could also do
`[a.format(name) for name in names]` instead of the map

Answer (score 1):

```
arr=["foo","goo","zoo"]
a="hello values: [xxxxx], have a good day"
for el in arr:
  print(a.replace("xxxxx",el))
```

Answer (score 1):

The replace function is what you're looking for :

```
a.replace('xxxxx','stringtoreplace')
```

if you want to go through the array then :

```
for str in stringarray:
     print(a.replace('xxxxx',str))
```

Answer (score 1):

My first intension is:

```
sentence = "hello values: [xxxxx], have a good day"
names = ["foo", "goo", "zoo"]

sentences = [sentence.replace("xxxxx", name) for name in names]
```

But I have a bad smell about your application ... it's a uncommon question.

Answer (score 0):

I will loop through the array and perform regular expression on it.

Looking for a pattern occurence of "[xxxxx]" and replacing that with whatever the array value is.

You can also just simply replace xxx with the array value but that can be unreliable anchoring to [xxx] is much safer as that is stricter.

Python's regular expression API.
https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: Thanks. Vote up on the question too because I don't see how this is a troll question, which have already received -2 response. Everyone start somewhere, especially topic on string manipulation.